# is there a risk to undervolting?

Tags: gpu

I read that overvolting is bad for your card and will cause it to wear out faster. does undervolting do the same and make the life longer, or does it wear out the unit as fast as or perhaps faster than overvolting?

i.e. reducing the power from about 1.5v to 0.987v

Comment: For reference: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/65824/can-electronics-be-damaged-by-undervolting-it

Answer (score 0):

It could be good for your hardware, but most hardware will last to its rated life at rated load.  Undervolting does reduce the amount of electricity and thus the wear on the card, however it increases the likelyhood of lockups and errors.  Its generally used to increase battery life or reduce heat disipation and thus noise.

Comment: only battery attached is a UPS- but that's continually charged from the wall. the device is built into a CPU so if it failed it has a chance of taking the central processor with it, thus I wanted to keep it running as long as possible.

Comment: I would think that too much undervolting would be bad. I've seen some electronics die due to brownouts and would think that this would follow a similar pattern.

Comment: I suspect that when stuff dies from brownouts its more likely due to the sudden changes in power and dirtyness of the power.  Take a look at http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/241164-28-undervolting-safe.  The bottom line is that transistors don't blow up from to low a voltage, they just don't switch, so no risk there.  Similarly, a major cause of eventual death in systems is the breakdown of paths in a CPU, which is accelerated by the amount of power use. Reversing the role, how do you see that reducing the voltage could damage the hardware.

Comment: I would expect maybe something like BS2 to possibly have a problem if the power fluctuates, though even that has it's own brownout reset circuit. currently I have it on the lowest setting my BIOS allows and it runs ok currently